# Xpages search between 2 dates

Tags: search, xpages, difference

I have a view with some data, and a column with the creation date of each document.
I want to make a search feature with 3 input fields:
Name, StartDate, EndDate.
The result of the search should be all the documents with the same name and within the 2 dates.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show us exactly what you've tried already? We don't like to do anything entirely for you here, as that breaks the learning process, but if you give it a good stab we'll help you as much as is needed. If necessary, I suggest you hit the books in order to know where to begin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `search` property of DominoView data source. It does a full text search on all documents in view. Create a search string like

```
[Name]="Meier" AND [_creationDate]>=12-01-2013 AND [_creationDate]<=30-08-2014
```

Your data source code would look like this:

```xml
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView
            var="view1"
            viewName="YourView">
            <xp:this.search><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            var search = "";
            var formatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            if (viewScope.Name) {
                search += ' AND [Name]="' + viewScope.Name + '*"';
            }
            if (viewScope.StartDate) {
                search += ' AND [_creationDate]>=' + formatter.format(viewScope.StartDate);
            }
            if (viewScope.EndDate) {
                search += ' AND [_creationDate]<=' + formatter.format(viewScope.EndDate);
            }
            return search.substring(5);}]]></xp:this.search>
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>
```

This code assumes that there are editable search fields which value is bound to `viewScope.Name`, `viewScope.StartDate` and `viewScope.EndDate` e.g.

```xml
<xp:inputText
    id="inputText1"
    value="#{viewScope.Name}">
</xp:inputText>

<xp:inputText
    id="inputText2"
    value="#{viewScope.StartDate}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime
            type="date"
            dateStyle="short">
        </xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
    <xp:dateTimeHelper></xp:dateTimeHelper>
</xp:inputText>
```