# Xpages, save a view into excel file

Tags: excel, view, xpages

I want to save a search report into an excel file but it is saving with the .xsp extension not excel.

I use the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" rendered="false">
<xp:this.afterRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript: 
var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext(); 
var writer = facesContext.getResponseWriter();
var response = exCon.getResponse();
var myView:NotesView = database.getView('vwSearch');
var viewNav:NotesViewNavigator = myView.createViewNav();
var viewEnt:NotesViewEntry = viewNav.getFirst();
print("2")
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
writer.write("<table>");
writer.write("<thead><tr>");
writer.write("<td><b>Column1Header</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Column2Header</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Column3Header</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Column4Header</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Column5Header</b></td>");
writer.write("</tr></thead>");
while (viewEnt != null) {
writer.write("<tr>");
writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[0] + "</td>");
writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[1] + "</td>");
writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[2] + "</td>");
writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[3] + "</td>");
writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[4] + "</td>");
writer.write("</tr>");
viewEnt = viewNav.getNext(viewEnt);
}
writer.write("</table>");
writer.endDocument()}]]></xp:this.afterRenderResponse>
</xp:view>
```

I use this code from a pdf... It is not my own creation, maybe something is wrong.

Thanks,

Florin

Comment: Florin, you might want to cleanup your code a little. Assign .getColumnValues() to a variable once and avoid string concatenation in writer.write. Add the missing .recycle()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a line

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=yourfile.xls");
```

or

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=yourfile.xls");
```

With "inline", the browser will try to open the file within the browser, whereas "attachment" will force it to download.

Comment: And how can I convert the type of data from view? Because I have a column that shows Data/Time and I only want the Time to appear in my excel.

Comment: You can use `dateTime.setAnyDate()` - it removes the date part from datetime value. Or, you convert it to Java Date with `.toJavaDate` and use a formatter to get the time.

Comment: How can I only export the documents after a search? How can I get only the documents in the searched view?

Comment: You'd add `myView.FTSearch("yourSearch")` right after line getView().

Comment: What you mean by "yourSearch"? The search function I'm using in the view's property search? Thanks

Comment: The view selection formula is always executed. You get only those documents which fit the selection formula. I understood your question that you want to have an additional "sub"-search on that view executed by .FTSearch. Look at Notes documentation for more information about this method http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_FTSEARCH_METHOD_VIEW_JAVA.html?lang=en

Comment: FTSearch only returns an int. How can this help me to return only the documents which fits the criteria?

Comment: Can I give the value of the search string: sessionScope.search? I want to filter after a used input, this is why I'm using a sessionScope. I tried but didn't work...

Comment: Yes, that is the right way to go. The parameter has to be a string. Easiest case is just a string like "Flop*" - it would search in all documents for a word that starts with "Flop". If you'd like to search only in a field "Name" you'd write '[Name]="Flop*"'.

Comment: Look here for an example with dates http://stackoverflow.com/a/25427890/2065611. It filters the data source dominoView. Thios is helpful if you want to show the filtered view in your XPage. But, you can also see how to construct such a search string.

Comment: Yea, I know, I was the one who asked the question, and I did like you said and worked... But now I don't know how to "play" with the documents that were filtered...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60060/discussion-between-knut-herrmann-and-flopet17).

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with this?

```
var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext(); 
var writer = facesContext.getResponseWriter();
var response = exCon.getResponse();
var myView:NotesView = database.getView('vwSearch');
myView.FTSearch("sessionScope.search");
var viewNav:NotesViewNavigator = myView.createViewNav();
var viewEnt:NotesViewEntry = viewNav.getFirst();

response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=raport.xls");
writer.write("<table>");
writer.write("<thead><tr>");
writer.write("<td><b>Nume</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Ora Intrare</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Ora Iesire</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Timp</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Timp 2</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Data Creare</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Email</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Telefon</b></td>");
writer.write("</tr></thead>");
while (viewEnt != null) {
 writer.write("<tr>");
 writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[0] + "</td>");
 writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[1].toJavaDate().getHours()+":"+viewEnt.getColumnValues()[1].toJavaDate().getMinutes() + "</td>");
 writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[2].toJavaDate().getHours()+":"+viewEnt.getColumnValues()[2].toJavaDate().getMinutes() + "</td>");
 writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[3] + "</td>");
 writer.write("<td>" + "08:00" + "</td>");
 writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[4].toJavaDate() + "</td>");
 writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[5] + "</td>");
 writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[6] + "</td>");
 writer.write("</tr>");
 viewEnt = viewNav.getNext(viewEnt);
}
writer.write("</table>");
writer.endDocument()
```

Even if I use: 
    myView.FTSearch("Jeff");
it will not show only documents with Jeff... Why?

Comment: Change line to `myView.FTSearch(sessionScope.search);` (without quotation marks) because you want to search for value of sessionScope.search and not the string "sessionScope.search".

Comment: Ups, just realized that **NotesViewNavigator ignores FTSearch**. You have to change your code to .getFirstDocument() and .getNextDocument()

Comment: Or, work with NotesViewEntryCollection. You can run an FTSearch on that.

Comment: With getFirstDoc and getNextDoc insteam of getFirst and getNext, it only returns one document.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are wanting to perform the search and export all in one step or not, but you could always modify the view selection formula and refresh the view.  Then provide the user an export button to follow the steps Knut is saying to modify your current code.  I have done this in a prior project where I opened the export in Excel and simply saved as a comma-delimited file.  In another project I am calling an Xagent that has code in the beforeRenderResponse to open in Excel after clicking of a button.  Just other options.