# XPages mobile search page and results

Tags: mobile, xpages, xpages-extlib

Can anyone help me to build a xpages mobile search?
I want a text field and a button that proceds a full text search on database and return a Dataview with the results.
Is there possible?

I don't know how to start this.

Comment: Surely you can find some starting point, somewhere. Please share something that you've tried.

Comment: I started creating something like this:  http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPagesViewControlAddFullTextSearch.htm   But the view control is strange, whithou CSS or document links. Do I have to build this manually?

Comment: Maybe you can do this using the XControls: http://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XControls

Comment: Marks, I didn´t know the XControls Project. Very nice look and feel e seems easy to use. I´ll read the documentation and make some tests. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach with a dataview is the same with a repeat or just a normal view.

You have a text field. In data for the text field go to advanced and use a scoped variable. Try view scope, that should work. and give the variable a name (exampleValue)

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText6" value="#{viewScope.exampleValue}"></xp:inputText>
```

You now have some data that you can reference with viewScope.exampleValue

In the search parameter compute this value and put in viewScope.exampleValue

```
<xe:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="Your view name" search="#{javascript:viewScope.exampleValue}">
```

Then have a button that does a partial refresh on the dataview

```
<xp:button value="Refresh Search" id="button1" >
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="ID_of_area_to_refresh">
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

Take a look at this question too. I can't upvote this answer enough. [Xpages search between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424109/xpages-search-between-2-dates)

You will also want to make sure you have initiated a ftindex, make sure you do that. You also want to make sure the FTindex is up to date, so put this code in some event somewhere.

```
database.updateFTIndex(true);
```

Here is the code you can use to clear a field.

```
<xp:button value="Label" id="button2"><xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="inputText1">
<xp:this.action>
    <xp:modifyField name="httppwd" var="viewscope" value=""></xp:modifyField>
</xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your help! In the button, where you say "ID_of_area_to_refresh", Do I have to put the Id of the DataView or DominoView? Sorry, but I´m really noobie on Xpages development.

Comment: Patrick, can you help me to build a "clear" button for the search results? I tried creating a button with code <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.remove("stringToSearch")}]]></xp:this.action> but it´s not working.

Comment: No problem Renan. I wouldn't have learned what I know if it wasn't for others. What I mean by ID_of_area_to_refresh is that you can choose to refresh things by ID. That ID can be one control like a field or it can be a container like a panel. So lets say you wanted to refresh 10 fields at the same time, you can put them all in a container and refresh that container but in you case if you just want to refresh one field you go to the events tab of a button put your code in and then pick a partial refresh to instead of refreshing the entire page just refresh that one ID.

Comment: So for your specific question you could put in the ID of the dataview. This will reload the dataview which will have a computed search that will now have a value. I added some code that will partially refresh the inputText1 ID and then change the value to null. Null will be a pair of "" with no space in between but you can only see it in the source view. Sometimes using the domino designer editor it won't let you put nothing in a field so you need to put a BS value and then go into the source to edit it. Let me know if I can help with anything else and mark the question as answered if it is.

Comment: Thanks! My search is working now! But the dataView loads the documents when I open the search page. I tried to set attribute loaded as false, but it generates a runtime error. Is this correct? Can I open search page without documents?

Comment: One way to do this is to set the visible/rendered property to not show if the a variable is "". That way the entire property is not rendered if there is no search criteria. One you refresh the id it will be visible and search with your results. I think this will work correctly.

Comment: When I do this, the runtime generates an error: "Invalid component id dataView1 for partial refresh". I think the action that refreshs the component can't "see" this hidden dataview.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense. You might need to put it in a panel and refresh the panel, everything in the panel gets refreshed.

Comment: I added the dataview inside a panel, but scripted loaded or rendered properties seems it not works. If I set them to true and refresh the panel, it works. I'll continue the tests.

Comment: I think we should move this conversation to chat or email. my email address is (<myFirstName>+<myLastName>+&#x40+gmail.com feel free to send me an email you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the View control or the Data View? Only the Data View works with the mobile controls.

Comment: I was using View control for tests only. I changed to the Dataview and I had some progress. Thanks