# xpages + Search in a view panel between 2 dates

Tags: search, view, xpages, lotus-notes

I have a view with some data, and a column with the creation date of each document. I want to make a search feature with 3 input fields: ip_address, StartDate, EndDate. The result of the search should be all the documents with the same ip_addressand within the 2 dates.

I use this link 
[Xpages search between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25424109/2065611)

but it return me this error

> Unexpected runtime error:The runtime has encountered an unexpected error.
>
> com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Notes error: Relational operators are not supported in text fields Notes error: Relational operators are not supported in text fields
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFapE.png)

this is the code of the search query:

```
        var search = "";
        var formatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        if (viewScope.StartDate) {
            search += ' AND [imp_dateTrace] >=' + formatter.format(viewScope.StartDate);
        }

        if (viewScope.EndDate) {
            search += ' AND [imp_dateTrace] <=' + formatter.format(viewScope.EndDate);
        }

        if (viewScope.imp) {
            search += ' AND [imp_IP]="' + viewScope.imp + '"';
        }
        if (viewScope.agence) {
            search += ' AND [imp_emplacement]="' + viewScope.agence + '"';
        }

        viewScope.searchquery = search;
        return viewScope.searchquery.substring(5);
```

Comment: It seems that you've posted someone else's question from another Q&A site. Do you have the same question as them? If you can add the code/query you're using in this site, that would be good too.

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25424109/2037229) SO

Comment: Add your source code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use `[_creationDate]` like showed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25427890/2065611) but your own field `imp_dateTrace`.

If field `imp_dateTrace` contains just document's creation date then use `[_creationDate]` instead. `[_creationDate]` will work as you don't depend on field types in documents.

If you have to use field `imp_dateTrace` then make sure your field is stored as a date field in documents.

If that is the case then database's UNK table might list this field as a text field. This can happen if it was first created as a text field and later got changed to a date field. You would have to fix the UNK table in this case:

- delete FT-index
- [compact](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21084388) database with option -c (copy-style)
- create new FT-index.

Make also sure your query doesn't start with " AND ". This would be the case   with your code shown in your question.