# Full text search does not work and the log file does not have error to show

Tags: xpages

Last month, I created a view that is indexed for full text search and I could perform in Louts client and on the web page.

Until today, I test all the functions in the web application and I notice the full text search is not working.

After I created the view and the search function, I did not "touch" that part for while, so I assume it should work. But in the web application, when I perform the search function, the view does not show any result. Then I search in Lotus client, it displays "0 results found in the view matched your search.".

I start to find out the problem, and I usually create a database backup when a function is completed. Therefore I use the latest backup database and see whether the full text search is working or not.

I feel strange that the search function in the backup database works well in web application and Lotus client.

In the current database, I delete the index and create it again, it cannot search. Even I ask my colleague to restart the server ( because I am not the administrator), the full text search is not working. I ask my colleague if there any log files in the server for diagnose. My colleagues  gives me a log file that is on 30/06/2016 start with "xpages_ex_servername_date@time.log", he said it is the newest log file and no log files in July.

I don't have any idea to solve this problem.

And here is the code I used to test to search in Lotus client:

```
FIELD dateYYYYMM >=201601 & FIELD dateYYYYMM <= 201612
```

All the code work properly in the backup database but the current database is not working even the whole design from the backup database and paste to the current database, the full text search is not working.

Is there any way that I can fix the problem? Grateful your advice please. Thank you.

---

Update: I removed some content in the previous version and add new information below for your advice please.

In the xpage, there is a table for use's selection for searching

```
<xp:table style="width:1100.0px" id="criteriaTable">
                <xp:tr><xp:td><xp:label value="ID" id="label2"></xp:label>  </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:200.0px">
                        <xp:comboBox id="idField" style="width:200.0px"  dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" value="#{sessionScope.idSearch}">
                            <xp:selectItems>
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var   SetFirstValueBlank = @Text("");

return SetFirstValueBlank;
}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:selectItems>
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#  {javascript:@DbColumn(@DbName(),"staffinfo",1);
}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"  refreshMode="partial" refreshId="criteriaTable"></xp:eventHandler></xp:comboBox>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:597.0px">

                    &#160;&#160;&#160;</xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td style="width:174.0px"><xp:label   value="Department" id="label1"></xp:label></xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:200.0px">

                    <xp:comboBox id="departmentField" style="width:200.0px"  dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" value="#{sessionScope.departSearch}">
                            <xp:selectItems>
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var  SetFirstValueBlank = @Text("");
return SetFirstValueBlank;
}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:selectItems>
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://get   id
var getValue = getComponent("idField").getValue();
//lookup in staffinfo view
@DbLookup(@DbName(),"staffinfo",getValue,2);
}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:selectItems>
                            </xp:comboBox></xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:597.0px"></xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td><xp:label value="Name" id="label3"></xp:label>  </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:200.0px">

                    <xp:comboBox id="nameField" style="width:200.0px"   dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" value="#{sessionScope.nameSearch}">


                            <xp:selectItems>
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var  SetFirstValueBlank = @Text("");

return SetFirstValueBlank;}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:selectItems>
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://get  id
var getValue = getComponent("idField").getValue();
//lookup in staffinfo view
@DbLookup(@DbName(),"staffinfo",getValue,3);}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:selectItems>
                            </xp:comboBox></xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:597.0px"></xp:td>
                </xp:tr>

                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td style="width:149.0px">
                        <xp:label value="Start Year and Month for search"  id="label28">
                        </xp:label>
                        <xp:br></xp:br>
                        <xp:label value="yyyymm" id="label29"></xp:label>   </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:200.0px">
                    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#  {sessionScope.startDateSearch}" style="width:200.0px">
            </xp:inputText></xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:597.0px">
                </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>

                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td style="width:149.0px">
                        <xp:label value="End Year and Month for search"   id="label31">
                        </xp:label>
                        <xp:br></xp:br>
                        <xp:label value="yyyymm" id="label32"></xp:label>  </xp:td><xp:td style="width:200.0px">
                    <xp:inputText id="inputText2" value="#  {sessionScope.endDateSearch}" style="width:200.0px"></xp:inputText></xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:597.0px">
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>

                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td style="width:149.0px"></xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:200.0px">

                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:597.0px">
                        </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td style="width:149.0px">

                        <xp:button value="Clear Selection" id="button1">
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="complete"   immediate="false"
                                save="false" id="eventHandler2">
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#  {javascript:sessionScope.divisionSearch = "";
sessionScope.rankSearch = ""
sessionScope.postSearch = "";
sessionScope.officerNameSearch = ""
sessionScope.startDateSearch = "";
sessionScope.endDateSearch = ""
}]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:button>
                        <xp:br></xp:br></xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:200.0px">
                        <xp:button value="Execute" id="button2">

                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"  refreshMode="complete">
                        </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
                        <xp:br></xp:br>
                        <xp:br></xp:br><xp:text escape="true"  id="computedField2" rendered="false"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://use   to check the query in text format

var qstring= "";

if ((sessionScope.idSearch != null && sessionScope.idSearch != "" )||
(sessionScope.departSearch != null && sessionScope.departSearch != "")&&
(sessionScope.nameSearch != null && sessionScope.nameSearch != "")||
(sessionScope.startDateSearch != null && sessionScope.startDateSearch !=     "")|| 
(sessionScope.endDateSearch != null && sessionScope.endDateSearch !=""))

{
    qstring = "FIELD id contains \"*" + sessionScope.idSearch + "*\"" + 
    " | FIELD department contains \"*" + sessionScope.departSearch + "*\"" +
    " | FIELD name contains \"*" + sessionScope.nameSearch + "*\"" +
    " & FIELD dateYYYYMM >=" + sessionScope.startDateSearch + 
    " & FIELD dateYYYYMM <=" + sessionScope.endDateSearch;
}

return qstring;
}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text></xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:597.0px">
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#  {sessionScope.queryString}">
                        </xp:text>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:table>
```

And the view is to display the search result.

```
<xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel2" viewStyle="width:600.0px">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="staffallocation"
            expandLevel="4">
            <xp:this.search><![CDATA[#{javascript:var qstring= "";

    if ((sessionScope.idSearch != null && sessionScope.idSearch != "" )||
(sessionScope.departSearch != null && sessionScope.departSearch != "")&&
(sessionScope.nameSearch != null && sessionScope.nameSearch != "")||
 (sessionScope.startDateSearch != null && sessionScope.startDateSearch !=   "")|| 
(sessionScope.endDateSearch != null && sessionScope.endDateSearch !=""))

{
    qstring = "FIELD id contains \"*" + sessionScope.idSearch + "*\"" + 
    " | FIELD department contains \"*" + sessionScope.departSearch + "*\"" +
    " | FIELD name contains \"*" + sessionScope.nameSearch + "*\"" +
    " & FIELD dateYYYYMM >=" + sessionScope.startDateSearch + 
    " & FIELD dateYYYYMM <=" + sessionScope.endDateSearch;
}

return qstring;}]]></xp:this.search>
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="name" id="viewColumn4">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Officer"
            id="viewColumnHeader4">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="allocationDate" id="viewColumn5">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Allocation  Date"
            id="viewColumnHeader5">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="department" id="viewColumn6">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Allocated Department"
            id="viewColumnHeader6">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:this.facets>

        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next"
            xp:key="footerPager" id="pager3">
        </xp:pager>
    </xp:this.facets>
</xp:viewPanel>
```

Description of the code: combo boxes are used for search staff id or department or staff name. User needs to to type the start date and end date use YYYYMM format. When click the button the view will display the result depends on the criteria. The result will show the officer name, officer allocation date and the allocated deartment.

Comment: Could you also provide the code in which the qstring is applied to the ftsearch?

Comment: Is the dateYYYYMM stored as a date or stored as a number?

Comment: @David Navarre, thanks your response. In the form, I have a  Date/Time type field called date and I choose Display Date only. The dateYYYYMM is a Text type field and is computed. It is used to convert the date to YYYYMM. The code is like this: `a:=@Text(@GetField("date")); year:=@Right(a; 4); monthyear:=@Right(a;7); month:=@Left(monthyear;2); year+month`

Comment: I feel I misunderstand the full text search, because I think `qstring = "FIELD id contains \"*" + sessionScope.idSearch + "*\"" + 
    " | FIELD department contains \"*" + sessionScope.departSearch + "*\"" +
    " | FIELD name contains \"*" + sessionScope.nameSearch + "*\"" +
    " & FIELD dateYYYYMM >=" + sessionScope.startDateSearch + 
    " & FIELD dateYYYYMM <=" + sessionScope.endDateSearch;` is the fts search

Comment: I still no idea why the code works fine in the backup database and the current database is not work, especially the current database is a new copy from the backup database.

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424109/xpages-search-between-2-dates)  inspire me to use `>=` and `<=` for date range search. So in the code `" & FIELD dateYYYYMM >=" + sessionScope.startDateSearch + " & FIELD dateYYYYMM <=" + sessionScope.endDateSearch;` is used to set a date range for search and if the allocationDate match the criteria, it will show in the view

Comment: I not sure that the LotusScript escape method of \" for inserting the double quotes works in SSJS. Try using single quotes to surround the double quotes instead 'FIELD id contains "*' + sessionScope.idSearch + '*"'

Comment: Wait, is there a full-text index at the database level for both the backup and current database or are you just talking about view indexes?

Comment: Hello everyone, I appreciate for your useful advice. Finally I can solve the problem.

Comment: I delete the xpage, view and the form. And then I recreate them, write same code for the function and run the application, the program works properly now. Again thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: @DavidNavarre, thank you for your comment. May I ask how to can I find the full-text index at the database level?

Comment: I right click the application, go to Application and select Properties. I click the 6th tab (Full Text) and I see the last index time, update frequency(servers only), index settings. So does that mean the full text index level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Notes Client view search options, selecting those fields to build up the search criteria. Do not just copy and paste your search criteria, because that will not give you the information you need. Check each field provides the correct options - id, department and name give "contains"/"does not contain", dateYYYYMM provides "is equal to"/"is less than" etc. (assuming it's supposed to be a number field).

If the same field name is used with different datatypes in a database, or a field's datatype is changed, this can affect full text searching. The search settings are held in the UNK table, which holds a mapping between a specific field name and its datatype. So dateYYYYMM field name has to be consistent across all Forms and all documents in the database. Otherwise, the data type of the first document created is what is stored and used for all full text queries. Restoring the design has no effect - it is the first document created which is the key to what datatype is stored in UNK table.

See http://www.intec.co.uk/full-text-search-musings/ for more information and resolving by updating all documents and using an offline compact.

Comment: Thanks your response. I visit the link and I learn UNK table means unique key table. However I don't understand how to apply the unique key table to the application. Should I use a view for it or something else? I search the keyword `xpages unique key table` in google but I don't get relevant result.

Comment: UNK table is not something you apply to the application. It is the internal table Domino uses for any full text search - you have no control over whether or not it is used. As I said, it is an internal table that keeps a track of the data type of a specific field name, driven by the documents in the database. Changes to the design of a database have no impact upon it. If the first document indexed as dateYYYYMM as a date field, every full text query treats dateYYYYMM as a date field, regardless of the design.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions.

Log the string in *qstring* so you can pick it up and paste it in the search bar in the Notes client.

I assume that when you execute the search, Notes will complain that it cannot use <= or => on text values. These operators are only defined "for numbers or dates in numeric or date fields only". See "How can I refine a search query using operators?" in the Notes Help database. So you have to build your search string or parameters differently.